# Cake php 3.0.1 saving data in orm

Tags: cakephp-3.0

am learning cakephp 3.0, in the form submit i got the form values as given below:

```
App\Model\Entity\User Object
(
    [new] => 1
    [accessible] => Array
        (
            [*] => 1
        )

    [properties] => Array
        (/*this properties array contain my form values*/
            [uName] => adfaf
            [password] => $2y$10$z2XFHdQ1qlNuIuPQebQcAODjeKfWFezE2lRPyXtfO2Nj70lJQttzS
            [fName] => 
            [mName] => 
            [lName] => 
            [mStatus] => Married
            [address] => 
            [City] => 
            [State] => 
            [Mobile] => 
        )

    [dirty] => Array
        (
            [uName] => 1
            [password] => 1
            [fName] => 1
            [mName] => 1
            [lName] => 1
            [mStatus] => 1
            [address] => 1
            [City] => 1
            [State] => 1
            [Mobile] => 1
        )

    [original] => Array
        (
        )

    [virtual] => Array
        (
        )

    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [repository] => users
)
 And in my controller i have written the code from cake book but i cann't understand what the following code is doing here.Kindly help me and give the clarifactions.

public function addEmployee() {
       $users = TableRegistry::get('users');
      $users = $users->newEntity($this->request->data());

    }
```

if i put the users  variable in var_dump means it gives the above object will be shown.And i have to store the values in different tables like users,employees,contact.Each table's have their foreign keys.Here the problem is i don't know how to save the values in appropriate tables.

Comment: Please read the docs to get a grasp on the basics: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first maybe you need read about [Saving With Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations), now I can give you tips:

in you controller maybe you need charge the model o you database:

```
$this->loadModel('Articles');
```

after of this, maybe you need create entities and save the data you receive in variables:

```
public function add()
{
    $this->loadModel('Articles');
    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $article = $this->Articles->newEntity();
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();

    //receive data
    $user->username = $this->request->data('uName');
    $user->password = $this->request->data('password');
    $user->fullname = $this->request->data('fName');

    //receive data
    $article->fullname = $this->request->data('City');
    $article->fullname = $this->request->data('State');
    $article->fullname = $this->request->data('Mobile');

    //save data
    $this->Travels->save($article);
    $this->Travels->save($user);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your great response widrogo.i have an doubt this save methods are related to orm?!